# Reduce( ): Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Item'

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, error-handling

I've been trying to get a total number of items using the `reduce()` method plus typescript and I'm getting the following errors:

***Argument of type '(accumulator: Item, currentValue: Item) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: Item, currentValue: Item, currentIndex: number, array: Item[]) => Item'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Item'.***

My code:

```
export type Item = {
  id: string;
  selected: boolean;
  label: string;
  numberOfItems: number;
};
```

```
const totalItems = items.reduce((accumulator: Item, currentValue: Item) => accumulator.numberOfItems + currentValue.numberOfItems);
```

Does anybody have a fix for this error? Thanks :)

Comment: because You are reducing to a number and accumulator is Item? You are not returning the accumulator

Comment: You declared `accumulator` to be of type `Item`. But you return `accumulator.numberOfItems + currentValue.numberOfItems` which is of type `number`. The return value is what is going to be passed to `accumulator`. The error message is saying that this doesn't make sense. And it doesn't. You probably just want `accumulator: number` and to pass an initial value of `0`.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for explaining! It was really helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

To understand how the `reduce` method works, it takes two argument, a reducer function and an initial value, and it will run the function for each item in the array and update the accumulator.

In your case the two arguments are:

- a reducer method, it will add `currentValue.numberOfItems` to the accumulator.
- an initial value for the accumulator, 0.

```
const reducer = (accumulator: number, currentValue: Item) =>
  accumulator + currentValue.numberOfItems;

const initialValue = 0;

const totalItems = items.reduce(reducer, initialValue);
```

which is the same as writing:

```
const totalItems = items.reduce(
  (accumulator: number, currentValue: Item) =>
    accumulator + currentValue.numberOfItems,
  0
);
```

The last sentence in the error message gives it away: `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Item'.`, which is the accumulator type in the reducer function.

Answer (score 0):

`accumulator`'s type is `Item` but you are returning `number`. Change the first argument type to `number` and also give the initial value as 0.

```
const totalItems = items.reduce(
  (totalNum: number, currentValue: Item) => totalNum + currentValue.numberOfItems,
  0
);
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very, very much!